# Display a paragraph in the index page that won't be displayed in the single post

Tags: content, excerpt

Can i make it possible for an excerpt to be displayed in the index page but that part of the excerpt will not be displayed in the single post anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly: use the "Excerpt" textarea on the Post Edit screen. It should be immediately beneath the "Content" textarea; if not, check Screen Options (tab in the upper right-hand corner), and ensure that the "Excerpt" checkbox is enabled/checked.